# JBoss AS6 Realm configuration

Tags: configuration, jboss, single-sign-on, jboss6.x

I'm configuring JBoss AS6 with [Jasig CAS SSO authority](http://www.jasig.org/cas) and JAAS. By [wiki tutorial](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/JAAS+Integration) of JBoss CAS and JAAS configuration I've changed `/opt/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/all/conf/login-config.xml` accordingly

```
<application-policy name="myRealm">
   <authentication>
      <login-module code="org.jasig.cas.client.jaas.CasLoginModule" flag="required">
         <module-option name="ticketValidatorClass">org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas10TicketValidationFilter</module-option>
         <module-option name="casServerUrlPrefix">https://cas.domain.com:8443/</module-option>
         <module-option name="defaultRoles">MYROLE</module-option>
         <module-option name="roleAttributeNames">memberOf,eduPersonAffiliation,authorities</module-option>
         <module-option name="principalGroupName">CallerPrincipal</module-option>
         <module-option name="roleGroupName">Roles</module-option>
         <module-option name="cacheAssertions">true</module-option>
         <module-option name="cacheTimeout">480</module-option>
         <module-option name="cacheAssertions">true</module-option>
      </login-module>
   </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

I've also changed `jboss-web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <security-domain>java:/jaas/myRealm</security-domain>
  <context-root/>
</jboss-web>
```

By remote debugging the app I've found that it falls to `JBossWebRealm` instead of `org.jasig.cas.client.jaas.CasLoginModule` class, so it looks like that I forgot some configuration.

**My goal is to authorize and authenticate user by CAS SSO authority and use JAAS inside the web app.**